# How to check if a key value pair (in an array) exists in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops

I have two arrays, for example:

```
invoices: [
    {id: 90, Client: 'Bob', paid: false, total: 900},
    {id: 91, Client: 'Sarah', paid: false, total: 400}
]
```

and:

```
result: [{km: 200, hours: 20, Person: 'Sarah'}]
```

The `invoices` array is a JSON response from a GET and will sometimes be larger than `result`, so I in this case `invoices` has Bob while it doesnt exist in `result`.

How can I get the `id` of any objects whose `Client` does not appear as `Person` in `result`? I tried to do it with a double `for` loop but it didn't quite work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By generating an object with keys which are the `Person`  values from `result`, we can use that to efficiently filter the values in `invoices`, and then use map to return only the `id` values of the filtered result:

```js
const invoices =  [
    {id: 90, Client: 'Bob', paid: false, total: 900},
    {id: 91, Client: 'Sarah', paid: false, total: 400}
]

const result =  [{km: 200, hours: 20, Person: 'Sarah'}]

const resindexes = result.reduce((c, o, i) =>
  (c[o.Person] = i, c), {});

ids = invoices.filter(o => resindexes[o.Client] === undefined).map(o => o.id);

console.log(ids);
```

Comment: === undefined? what do you mean

Comment: @user3660293 only `Person` names that are in `result` will be a property in the `resindexes` object, so `resindexes[o.Client]` will be `undefined` for any `Client` name which was not in `result`. This allows us to filter invoices to only return the ones whose `Client` isn't in result.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the `invoices` Array, using the `result` Array as this-argument and check for any `Client` in that ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for `Array.filter`). Note, the `filter`-callback should be a normal function (i.e. not an arrow function) to be able to use the result-Array for `thisArg`.

```js
console.log( `Id(s) not in result\n`, 
  [ {id: 90, Client: 'Bob', paid: false, total: 900}, 
    {id: 91, Client: 'Sarah', paid: false, total: 400},
    {id: 92, Client: 'Mia', paid: false, total: 200} ]
  .filter( 
    function(v) { return !this.find(n => n.Person === v.Client); }, 
    [{km: 200, hours: 20, Person: 'Sarah'}] // <= thisArg
   )
   .map(v => v.id) // <= fetch the found id's
   .join()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Change `filter(...)` to `filter(...).map( (invoice) => invoice.id )`

Comment: `map( (invoice) => invoice.id )` does not exist in the answer

Comment: That's why I suggested making the change, which will give you a list of just the `id`s you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using Set and flatMap makes for an expressive, efficient solution. Set consumes an array and lets you check for members in constant time. flatMap lets you filter and map at the same time, in essence.

```js
// Data
const invoices = [
  {id: 90, Client: 'Bob', paid: false, total: 900},
  {id: 91, Client: 'Sarah', paid: false, total: 400}
];
const personsArr = [{km: 200, hours: 20, Person: 'Sarah'}];

// Query
const persons = new Set(personsArr.map(r => r.Person));
const result = invoices.flatMap(i => !persons.has(i.Client) ? i.id : []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it by make persons Map.

Plus of that attempt is you have access to person data by client name.

*Notice I incremented **invoices** for 1 row for better result view.*

```js
// Data enter code here
const invoices = [
    {id: 90, Client: 'Bob', paid: false, total: 900},
    {id: 91, Client: 'Sarah', paid: false, total: 400},
    {id: 92, Client: 'Joe', paid: false, total: 400}
];
const personsArr = [{km: 200, hours: 20, Person: 'Sarah'}];

// Query
const persons = new Map(
    personsArr.map(r =>{ 
        return [r.Person, r]
    }
  )
);
// invoices which do not have results
const orphans = invoices.filter((i)=>!persons.has(i.Client));
// id of invoices which do not have results
const orphansId = orphans.map((o)=>o.id)

console.log(orphansId);
```

it returns: [
  90,
  92
]